# if NTFS partition is not good for Ubuntu 20.04 which partition type should I make for Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

On my 1 TB disk  I have windows 10 and have 264 Gig free.
How do I make a specific partition for Ubuntu on this?

Comment: Hello. Personally I would let the installation make the partition for you. Unless you have some special needs. Use a Windows tool to free up the partition for the Ubuntu install and do not set it to any type. Just have it be free space.

Comment: This already shows a very typical newbie mistake: Over-partitioning.

Comment: You cannot use NTFS for Linux. Default install would then just try to shrink some NTFS partition to make space. Better just to delete the NTFS partition to make unallocated. or in gparted change to ext4 for / (root) then in Something else choose that partition reset to ext4 and specify as /. If new user, just having one larger partition is fine. Then later you may want separate /home or data partition(s) once you have some idea of use. Note that NTFS works best if 30% free, so you have space for defrag. Linux does not need defrag but also needs some extra space.

Answer (score 1):

Make at least 25 GB or more depending on your disk space requirements of unallocated disk space and let the Ubuntu installer make an ext4 partition (the default partition type) on the unallocated disk space. If you don't make unallocated disk space, the Ubuntu installer will take some of the disk space that is currently being used by Windows and create a partition for Ubuntu for you which is formatted as ext4 by default.

A fresh installation of Ubuntu installs root, home and swap on a single ext4 partition, and sometimes it also creates a small separate EFI System partition (~500MB) for the bootloader to be launched by the UEFI firmware which is formatted as FAT by default by the Ubuntu installer. In your screenshot it looks like there is already an EFI System partition that is being used to boot Windows, so the Ubuntu installer would not create another one.

If the default partitioning does not meet your requirements you can select the *Something else* option in the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer and manually create or resize partitions yourself.